# JasperReport image dynamic vertical stretching depending on page size - can it be done?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report that looks like a certificate.

I have a background image that serves as the attractive bordering or frame of the whole page.

The problem is, if for example, the name in text field is much bigger than the element container, it creates extra white space in the bottom.

The background image / frame is not stretching to stretch the the whole edges of the page.

The same is true when the text fields are shorter. But in this case, the page is shortened to the point that you almost cannot see the bottom portion of the frame.

I want the image to dynamically stretch depending on the final size of the page at runtime.

Here is the look of my design:
[image]

This is what happens when it is compiled, as you can see there are extra white spaces at the bottom:
[image]

This is the current setting of my image..

[image]

Position Type: Float

Stretch Type: ContainerBottom

**The jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.8.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="paiwi-certificate-pdf" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="792" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="28bcb6f8-04d6-48df-ab31-e1bedc2f2434">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="farmContactListSubreportDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="farmName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="farmLogo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="farmAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="farmBusinessAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="temporaryPartnersName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="partnerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="partnerContactNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="partnerEmail" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="packageName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="batchName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="612" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="146" y="80" width="224" height="40" forecolor="#332411" uuid="cb95bd0b-631e-4363-80f5-22d0b0e481fe">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="34" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CERTIFICATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="50" y="372" width="446" height="28" uuid="6281f2a7-4eca-4319-b298-22184617a6d3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="24" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{farmName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="50" y="400" width="446" height="17" uuid="f19dc14b-3ada-460b-8633-85fd5a896d45">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="14" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{farmAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="50" y="417" width="446" height="17" uuid="dec9944a-2758-4202-acfe-6f97df346b8f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="14" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{farmBusinessAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="164" y="180" width="473" height="40" forecolor="#332411" uuid="b2a59bb8-1557-498f-b17a-3f0e561bb11b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="37" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{partnerName} != null && !$P{partnerName}.equalsIgnoreCase("") ? $P{partnerName} : $P{temporaryPartnersName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="569" y="338" width="164" height="160" uuid="717d6475-3d42-4e54-a69a-7271bc862e33"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{farmLogo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="416" y="81" width="228" height="40" forecolor="#332411" uuid="f2a78f2d-ed74-45b9-89e8-3365c4afe801">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="34" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[COMPLETION]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="378" y="80" width="33" height="40" forecolor="#332411" uuid="e1c7ac87-81ce-4e8d-b718-2aee4f139003"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="34" isBold="false" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[of]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="311" y="148" width="179" height="15" forecolor="#6E6E6E" uuid="3d5afae8-14e2-4a3b-8471-db8388e2309f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[THIS ACKNOWLEDGES THAT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="290" y="249" width="232" height="15" forecolor="#6E6E6E" uuid="4c301efe-c460-478e-873a-d16430000b18">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[HAS SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED THE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="50" y="357" width="232" height="15" forecolor="#6E6E6E" uuid="1060f753-1051-4925-9efe-c2ee62146b25">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ACKNOWLEDGED BY:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="275" y="279" width="263" height="17" uuid="3ab3ec94-b64f-42df-b475-7996bcac1abb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="14" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{packageName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="359" y="296" width="43" height="16" forecolor="#000000" uuid="c6e10785-2750-4247-af0c-6cbafa3aa294"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Batch:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="402" y="296" width="48" height="16" forecolor="#000000" uuid="dff76163-3fd3-4bf6-94fd-de4612485e29">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Georgia" size="14" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{batchName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="140" y="279" width="126" height="30" uuid="b0c2acd4-1a0c-4fe6-9a94-be43fe67d704"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://i.imgur.com/Ug4T4oX.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="550" y="279" width="126" height="30" uuid="9d2cddda-e519-42e2-b74b-554f4c102ef2"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://i.imgur.com/paQHNxJ.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape" vAlign="Bottom" onErrorType="Blank" evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="782" height="612" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="2dadd1da-0694-4e21-86de-fae790844411">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://i.imgur.com/y8uffu8.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you add the jrxml (this way we can see where you have the different elements), maybe it's easier to remove white space?. If you create a [mcve] I will have look. It's also bit unclear what the actual page size on your report is?

Comment: hi Petter, thanks for your response. Here is the .jrxml of the jasperreport.. https://pastebin.com/xW3wBQbD =)

Comment: My page size for this one is on the LETTER format, landscaped. width = 792px, height = 612px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only problem is that you do not have the correct `scaleImage` property set, hence the element is actually resizing but since you have `scaleImage="RetainShape"` the image will not fill the new element dimension but instead maintain orignal image proportions

From Jasper Reports Ultimate guide:

> - Clipping the image: If the actual image is larger than the image element size, it will be cut off so that it keeps its original
>     resolution, and only the region that fits the specified size will be
>     displayed (`scaleImage="Clip"`).
> - Forcing the image size: If the dimensions of the actual image do not fit those specified for the image element that displays it, the image
>     is forced to obey them and stretch itself so that it fits in the
>     designated output area. It will be deformed if necessary
>     (`scaleImage="FillFrame"`).
> - Keeping the image proportions: If the actual image does not fit into the image element, it can be adapted to those dimensions while
>     keeping its original undeformed proportions
>     (`scaleImage="RetainShape"`).
> - Stretching the image keeping the width: The image can be stretched vertically to match the actual image height, while preserving the
>     declared width of the image element (`scaleImage="RealHeight"`).
> - Stretching the image adjusting the width: The image can be stretched vertically to match the actual image height, while adjusting
>     the width of the image element to match the actual image width
>     (`scaleImage="RealSize"`).

So you need:

```
scaleImage="FillFrame"
```

*something like this*

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame" vAlign="Bottom" onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="10" y="0" width="782" height="612" uuid="2dadd1da-0694-4e21-86de-fae790844411">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://i.imgur.com/y8uffu8.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've been trying to solve this whole day when the answer is right there, staring at me. I finally got it fixed following your solution. I also set the image alignment to middle on both horizontal and vertical alignment, if that helps.